# Understanding the present participle - "I am happy to see you" versus "I am happy, seeing you"

Tags: difference, infinitives, present-participles

> I am happy to see you.

It is grammaticaly correct sentence, ok.
I want to make little alterations to the sentence as below.

> I am happy, seeing you.

Note that I intend to use *"seeing you"* as a present participle phrase. I want to be informed whether this is correct usage of participle phrase.

Secondly what is the difference between two sentences in terms of meaning? What different meaning could participle phrase impose, replacing "*to see you"*?

Comment: Since not any satistfying answer were given to me,I altered my question ,involving participle clauses.

Comment: It would be better to edit more information into the original question than to ask a very similar second question. Sometimes it takes more than a day to get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I am happy to see you.

Here the *happiness* is restricted to the event (seeing you).

> I am happy, seeing you.

Here the *happiness* is more general, with a loose connection to "seeing you". The comma accomplishes this separation.

Comment: So what exactly does the second example mean then? the act of being happy is realised through the expression "seeing you"?